# How can I share user profiles between different subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, user-profile

I have a home site based on Sharepoint Foundation 2010 with FBA and many different subsites.

I have defined all users profiles in the home site, but now I have the problem that I need to add again users for each subsites.

In addition doing this cause that user profiles information are not inherited from the home site and I need to insert again all personal data.

Is it possible share user profiles between different subsites?

Answer (score 1):

By subsites do you mean you have

- 1 site collection with many subsites
- or 1 site collection at the root and many site collections underneath that

The first one shares profile information already, the second one doesn't (in foundation).

The profile sharing feature is pretty much what you are paying for when you go with the standard/enterprise sharepoint editions.

You could either buy a third party component to do it for you:

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-user-profile-sync.aspx

Or you could build a SPJobDefinition that keeps all the information in the "User Information List" synchronized between your site collections.

Comment: the second, 1 site collection at the root and many site collections underneath that